# Will my votes be reversed if I delete my account

Tags: discussion, accounts

If I delete my account then will my votes (up and down) be reversed or will they remain as it is?

Comment: It depends how active you've been and how disruptive it would be if that happened.

Comment: Why would you care?

Comment: @MartinJames: Maybe some socks would get disappointed ;)

Comment: @MartinJames i up-voted many posts. And if i delete my account will all the users lose reputation gained by my up votes or it will have no effect.

Comment: @honk you might think that, I could not possibly comment:)

Comment: @rustybit  meh - you are just some anonymous user who decided to delete their account, so why would they care much?   It's not like they know you, or are in your office, and can come over and hit you with a staple gun for blowing their rep.

Comment: @MartinJames: We would never want to accuse anyone, right? ;)

Comment: @honk absoultely right.  It's a sub-clause of the 'be nice' policy.

Comment: @MartinJames they will not care but i care, as a user i up-voted many good quality questions and if i delete account those users may be affected.

Comment: The votes have to go, else immoral users would keep opening sockpuppets, voting for their master and deleting to cover their tracks.

Comment: You've only cast about 300 votes. That's not a whole lot, almost certainly not enough for SE to go to extra steps to preserve them. So yes, most likely, deleting your account would reverse the votes you have cast.

Answer (score 28):

In short, yes. Your votes disappear with your account. There are [some criteria which prevent that from happening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608), but in a huge majority of cases those criteria do not apply.